# React Router / Express - Refreshing dynamic URL parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

My React router works fine when navigating to '/Article/1/' via a link, though when I refresh my browser, it no longer detects my Article component.

**Root.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../page/Home/Index';
import Article from '../page/Article/Index';

const Root = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to={'/'}>Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to={'/About'}>About</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <hr />
        <Route exact path={'/'} component={Home} />
        <Route path={'/Article/:id'} component={Article} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Root;
```

**Server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.listen(9000, function() {
  console.log('listening on 9000.')
});
```

I read online that it may be related to me not having a wildcard in my server.js - could anyone point me in the right direction? thank you in advance!

**EDIT** -  this is what I tried (still not rendering):

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'))

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: FWIW `BrowserRouter` will use `browserHistory` behind the scenes, you don't need to explicitly set it (unless your changing `browserHistory` in some way).

Comment: May have something to do with URL rewrites. I had this problem on non-root routes where refreshing returns 404. Though, this problem might've been solved already since it's been a long time since this question was posted.

Answer (score 2):

> I read online that it may be related to me not having a wildcard in my server.js

Yep, that'll be it. The goal here is to have your client handle the routing and not the server, for that to work you need the server to return the client app regardless of what URL it gets.

Simple fix - change `/` to `/*` on your server route.

Comment: So I've amended to 'app.use('/*', express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));' but still have no luck

Comment: @danjones_mcr apologies I misread your code sample, I see your using `use` and not `get`. So to clarify, does your HTML render from the server? Is this a client-side problem?

Comment: It is being served from the server yes - I believe this may be a server issue, should I be using 'get'?

Comment: @danjones_mcr it would be simpler, you can do `app.use(express.static(...))` to set your static folder and then `app.get('/*', ...)` to serve the HTML from any URL.

Comment: ahhh I see, hmm still hasn't done the trick, see my edit on the Q

Comment: @danjones_mcr what isn't working though? is the HTML being served? (check the network tab in your browser). If the HTML page is being served correctly then the issue is with your client routing.

Comment: Ahh, So the HTML is being served, though the components aren't rendering, is this maybe an issue with my roots.js?

Comment: @danjones_mcr sounds like it, check to make sure your `Root.js` is actually being mounted.